# Effects of changing datatype of a column from varchar to text

Tags: mysql, database

The text data I have for a column in database in an enterprise application (uses hibernate) is huge and after increasing varchar size to a specific number, I don't have any other choice but to change the datatype to text. Can anyone help me understand how it may affect my application. Do I need to take care of anything else or just changing the datatype works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **TEXT.** Although, that's the same thing as **VARCHAR**:

> If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR",
>   "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the
>   type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT
>   affinity

Also note

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type
>   name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not
>   impose any length restrictions (other than the large global
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric
>   values.

Your application work fine with datatype text.You don't need to take care of any thing

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be sure, create backup database first just in case, 
or at least backup/duplicate table you were going to make changes

for me I also prefer varchar than text
because varchar used to be using smaller memory than text

ex : address (100) , records only using 80 character, will be saved as 80 character in varchar 
while in text , will be saved as 100 character

Comment: i don't have a choice here as my row size has reached 65535 bytes. I have taken backup and everything seems to be working fine with text. Just want to be sure that I don't miss anything.